# Grafana graphs jumping - local influxdb data source

Tags: ruby, influxdb, grafana

I have grafana-server installed along with influxdb and small ruby app on one vps. 3G ram, 2vcpus, 50G ssd, 512M swap.

- Ruby is writing data to influxdb.
- Grafana is reading data from influxdb.

Everytime grafana refreshes dashboard with some data, this happens:
[click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ksv3B.png)

---

That is about 200 writes per second. Dashboard for 30 minutes, refreshing every 1 minute (one user on grafana only). Query:

```
SELECT count("message") FROM "chat_message" WHERE $timeFilter GROUP BY time(1s) fill(0)
```

Can I do something about that?

Comment: Ideas I've had: separate nodes for grafana, influx and ruby app - influx relay to separate reads and writes - turn of refreshing on grafana dashboard

Comment: What version of InfluxDB are you using?